# Mysql Connection to Local Area Network

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench

im am working on application with mysql server its working fine.
but my program needs to be use in other computer Via Local Area Network
i have no idea how to do it can you guys please help me? thanks in advance

P.S sorry for my english

Comment: which one is _working fine_? do you already get the application working?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: package barangayinformationsystem;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class DatabaseConnection {
 Connection conn=null;
 public static Connection dbConnector(){
  try{
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.6.103/brgydatabase?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false","User","Password");
   return conn;
  }catch(Exception e){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e );
   return null;
  }
 } 
} This is my code in connection using netbeans

Comment: yes my application is working my only problem is how can other computer use my database in my Main Computer

Answer (score 0):

1) first check the connectivity of computer in which mysql is running by cmd:

telnet <ip of computerin which mysql is running> <port of mysql>

For ex:
telnet 10.21.23.34 3306

2) Then we connection details use the ip address of mysql computer **ip address** instead of **localhost**.

Comment: i already done that but still wont work

Comment: Thank folk fo yah help i get connection now. but cant insert data even if i already check all the privileges. :( so sad but thanks again :)

Comment: What error you r getting while inserting data ?

Comment: i already figure out whats wrong hehe thanks btw